# Read excel file that contains decimal with dot separator

Tags: c#, excel

I try to open an excel file and to preview it in a datagridview. I use a C# code, `OleDbAdapter` and datatable in order to contain the result of my request.

when my excel file contains decimal values with comma separator as:

```
1     1525,23     2514,589      -0,985
1     1845,28     3414,689      -0,985
```

everything is ok and my datagridview is filled correctley (NB: I use a french OS).

But, sometimes some decimal values in the excel file are written with dot separator instead of comma like:

```
1     1525,23     2514,589      -0.985
1     1845,28     3414,689      -0.985
```

So, when I check my datatable, I find that the first decimal value with dot separator is registred like this `-0#985` instead of `-0.985` (and this happens just with the first one).

Comment: Bigger question... Why do you have 2 different decimal separators in the same file?? That's usually a bad idea... Is it by design or is the file somehow corrupted?

Comment: @pnuts, no I do not want to replace '#' with ',' but I want just to read my excel content as it is. So, my datatable, for this example, will contains -0.985 instead of -0#985

Comment: @JohnBustos, YES I agree with you, but this excel file is created by our client by this way. So, if i can find an issue it's ok else i'm going to ask them to use the same separator.